# ROS QoS vs ROS2 QoS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anyway to have similar QoS policies to ROS (as the ones in ROS2) ?
Or is this a DDS specific feature?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353611/ros-qos-vs-ros2-qos/) by [KiD](https://answers.ros.org/users/54787/kid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a DDS specific feature (and actually one of the reasons DDS was chosen as the default middleware for ROS 2).

The things you can change to the ROS 1 "QoS" (in quotes, as it isn't really the same thing) are specified in the [TransportHints](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Transport_Hints) structure.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1